# creating my own docker image for archlinux and how to use it for development

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn docker. So i am trying to create an archlinux image. Presently i am not worried of size. But i am stuck up how to further go ahead to use this as my development for a project. My goal is to create and use different archlinux images for my different projects separately.

```
1) shift to root in terminal

2) mkdir archlinux

3) pacstrap -i -c -d ./archlinux base

4) echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' > ./archlinux/etc/locale.gen

5) arch-chroot ./archlinux locale-gen

6) echo 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' > ./archlinux/etc/locale.conf
```

Now the total size of the folder archlinux is `899 MB.`

Now i am trying to import it as an docker image

```
cd archlinux

tar -c . | docker import - example_archlinux

tar: ./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/S.gpg-agent: socket ignored
tar: ./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra: socket ignored
tar: ./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh: socket ignored
tar: ./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/S.scdaemon: socket ignored
tar: ./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser: socket ignored
sha256:2b3ed6536389a1184f402ff5a9d20380a3f4aa2c49bdee31df9c7c10186eb889
```

Now I run the docker image

```
#  docker images          
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
example_archlinux   latest              2b3ed6536389        About a minute ago   881MB
```

Now i try to run the image:

```
#  docker run -ti example_archlinux:latest /bin/bash
[root@3863ba31186b /]#

#  docker run -ti example_archlinux:latest ls -al           
total 52
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:32 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:32 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Oct 16 08:32 .dockerenv
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  5  2018 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Oct 16 08:32 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:32 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  5  2018 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  5  2018 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  5  2018 lib64 -> usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  5  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  5  2018 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 275 root root    0 Oct 16 08:32 proc
drwxr-x---   3 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  5  2018 sbin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Oct 16 08:32 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:10 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root 4096 Oct 16 08:01 var
```

Its great. Its working

```
Q1 : Will docker not ask for login and password of root, assuming i have set root passwd
```

I want to create my Django + ngingx + postgresql + redis + git. I will install and setup the required packages. 
.
So i am testing whether run command will save the folders craeted

```
#  docker run -ti example_archlinux:latest /bin/bash
[root@9f4e56ce38c5 /]# mkdir hare      
[root@9f4e56ce38c5 /]# exit

#  docker run -ti example_archlinux:latest ls /hare
ls: cannot access '/hare': No such file or directory
```

I have the main question:

```
Q2 Since i created a folder and if i exit its not there anymore. 

Now what is the best way to use a docker image for my development. 

I cant afford that my files are not there after i exit.

So is there any way that the container is permanently created and i can work in it for my development.
```

OR

Where to create my source code on host or docker. I want everything at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** I never tried setting the root password. But usually, when running the container, you'll be logged in as root except if you use the `USER` Dockerfile command, which is the more secure approach. More about it [here](https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b)

**Q2:** Everytime you remove your container, everything inside of it will be destroyed. So, you'll lose the files you've created, unless you bound a volume to your host. Volumes are the standard way to go. You can define a volume, for instance, on your `docker run` command:

`docker run -ti -v /host/source/folder:/desired/guest/folder example_archlinux:latest ls -al`

Now you can add/remove/change files both from container or host and it will be persisted. There wont be duplicated files. It's just that both have access to it.

more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume)

Comment: So we never keep the source code of the project inside the docker. We only mount it either be in the production or development

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi, when talking about code, usually you don't need to mount it in production. Ideally, in production you usually have a photograph built in a docker image of the state that your code files should be. So, you only need the last version of your code that was deployed. But if you think about Databases, then yes. Production will also have a mount so this databases can persist their files on the server. So, it depends on your case.